# The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, printf

```
package age;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AgeTest 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Age myAge = new Age();

    System.out.printf("initial age is :%s%n%n"+ myAge.getAge());

    System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER THE AGE");
    int theAge = input.nextInt(); 
    myAge.setAge(theAge);
    System.out.println();
    // display the name stored in object myAge
    System.out.printf("age in object myAge is %n%s%n"+ myAge.getAge());
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: this my first time using java :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your getAge() method is returning an int. So try parsing the myAge.getAge() to String like:

`String age = Integer.toString(myAge.getAge())`
 `System.out.print("Age is: " + age );`

Comment: Change your `System.out.printf("initial age is :%s%n%n"+ myAge.getAge());` line for this ----> `System.out.printf("initial age is :%s%n%n"+ Integer.toString(myAge.getAge()));` and do the same in the last printf.